# I want to know how to add items to an arraylist

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

Here is my code:-

```
   If FirstNameText.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your first name please")
    End If
    If SurnameText.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your surname please")
    End If
    If (Not RB_Male.Checked) AndAlso (Not RB_Female.Checked) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select your gender")
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select your year group")
    End If
    If TextStudentID.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select the generate button to give you a unique student ID")
    End If
     "in this section I want to add all the submitted items to an arraylist so a user's name pops up in the list box"
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

That's the only bit of code that I have written and have looked everywhere for an answer to submit items to an arraylist. The " " area is where i'm planning to submit the items to an arraylist. Any help or link to a good guide we do.

Comment: Don't use ArrayList. It's still there for compatibility with old code, but there's no good reason to use it in new projects.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? It's not clear what you are trying and why it doesn't work. To answer your title: `arraylist.Add(yourObject)`

Comment: Hold on i'll update the whole post and explain what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make a class for your student information

```
Class Student
    Public FirstName As String
    Public Surname As String
    Public Gender As String
    Public YearGroup As String
    Public StudentId As String
End Class
```

Second, I would use a `List` not an `ArrayList`, and make sure this is at the class level so it can be used throughout your code

```
Private StudentList As New List(Of Student)
```

Third, after you validate your data from your controls on your form, you would instantiate a `Student` object and then add it to your `StudentList`.  Once you're done adding all new `Student` data, you can access your `StudentList` in other methods to do whatever you want

```
' Validate all fields have data for a new student
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstNameText.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your first name please")
    FirstNameText.Focus()
    Return
ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(SurnameText.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your surname please")
    SurnameText.Focus()
    Return
ElseIf Not RB_Male.Checked AndAlso Not RB_Female.Checked Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please select your gender")
    Return
ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please select your year group")
    Return
ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextStudentID.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please select the generate button to give you a unique student ID")
    GenerateButton.Focus()
    Return
End If

' Create your new Student object
Dim NewStudent As New Student()
NewStudent.FirstName = FirstNameText.Text
NewStudent.Surname = SurnameText.Text
If RB_Male.Checked Then
    NewStudent.Gender = "M"
Else
    NewStudent.Gender = "F"
End If
NewStudent.YearGroup = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
NewStudent.StudentId = TextStudentID.Text

' Add your new student object to your List
StudentList.Add(NewStudent)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the code I edited will be of some help to you :) Also the `//<Text>` I added may help you as well as to how to edit the ArrayList.

Comment: Hopefully this Answers your Question on how to get the arraylist into the Listbox so first you need to declare the array which is Dim {ArrayName} as arraylist = new arraylist which then you convert your Textbox's to the arraylist which is just {ArrayName}.Add(TextboxName) then to display them in the listbox it is just {ListboxName}.Items.AddRange(ArrayName.ToArray())